# Non-linear recurrence with square root: $a_{n+2}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}\cdot a_{n}}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, radicals

How should I approach this problem:

$a_{n+2}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}\cdot  a_{n}}$
where $a_0 = 2, a_1=8$

Comment: Take $b_n=ln(a_n)$

Comment: See (http://openstudy.com/study#/updates/51f01b28e4b0c8f6bc348513)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may notice that $a_n>0$, for $n\ge0$, and that
$$
\log(a_{n+2})=\frac12\log(a_{n+1})+\frac12\log(a_{n}).
$$

Comment: What question did you answer??

Comment: @DonAntonio I gave a hint to obtain a closed form of $\log(a_n)$ thus to obtain a closed form of $a_n$.

Comment: Also, take logs to base 2 ...

Comment: @Mark Bennet I dont understand the purpose of your remark.

Comment: @JeanMarie Well it doesn't make a huge amount of difference, but for checking by hand with the initial values given, it makes all the terms rational, and the initial values are integers - so it would be easier to see what is going on than with natural logs or base ten.

Comment: @Mark Bennet Thank you. I understand now.

Comment: @OlivierOloa My comment was due to the fact that in the OP there is **no question at all**: it is a matter *of guessing* what the OP wants: the closed form, to prove it is monotone ascending/descending, its limit...? You guessed the OP wanted a closed form. Perhpas you're right...or not: I honestly can't say anything here.

Comment: @DonAntonio OK, I understand what you mean, but I think this is not a big deal, since for the above sequence once you get the closed form you may deduce the limit.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach to the one given by Oliver Oloa:
$$a_{n+2}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}\cdot  a_{n}}$$
$$\implies a^2_{n+2}={a_{n+1}\cdot  a_{n}}$$
$$\implies \frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+2}} \tag1$$

Similarly we can write that
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n+1}} \tag2$$
$$\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{a_{n-2}}{a_{n}} \tag3$$
$$\ldots$$
$$\frac{a_{2}}{a_{1}}=\frac{a_{0}}{a_{2}}  \tag{n+1}$$

Multiplying these $n+1$ relations, we get 
$$\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}\cdot\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\cdot\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}\ldots \frac{a_{2}}{a_{1}}=\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+2}}\cdot\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n+1}}\cdot\frac{a_{n-2}}{a_{n}}\ldots\frac{a_{0}}{a_{2}}$$
$$\implies \frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{1}}=\frac{a_{1}\cdot a_{0}}{a_{n+2}\cdot a_{n+1}}$$
$$\implies \frac{a_{n+2}}{8}=\frac{16}{a_{n+2}\cdot a_{n+1}}$$
$$\implies a_{n+2}=\frac{12}{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}$$
$$\implies a_{n+2}=\sqrt{12}\cdot \sqrt[4]{a_{n}}$$
$$\implies \boxed{a_{n}=\sqrt{12}\cdot \sqrt[4]{a_{n-2}}}$$

So we can write that $$a_{n}=12^{1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8}+\ldots + \frac{(-1)^{r-1}}{2^{r-1}}}\cdot (a_{n-r})^{\frac{(-1)^r}{2^r}} \,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{where} \,\,\, r \ge 1$$

For $r=n$, we get
$$a_{n}=12^{\frac{1-(-\frac{1}{2})^n}{1-(-\frac{1}{2})}}\cdot (a_0)^{\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}}$$
$$\boxed{a_{n}=12^{\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2^n-(-1)^n}{2^{n-1}}}\cdot (2)^{\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}}} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall \,\,\,\,\,\, n\ge0$$

This is the closed form.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: There is a slightly simpler form: $a_n=a^{7 - \frac{4}{(-2)^n}}$ with $a=2^{1/3}$.